# Set Multiple UserDefaults Values with single function Swift 3

Tags: swift, function, swift3, nsuserdefaults

i have a game and im trying to keep it small and in my game i have this function

```
func deductCoins() -> Bool {

    if price > coins {
        label.text = String("You dont have enough coins")
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        return false
    }
    if coins >= price {
        coins = coins - price
        UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
        BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        label.removeFromSuperview()
        image.removeFromSuperview()
        return true
    }

    return true
}
```

this function is used to buy in-game content is there a way to pass in a parameter or method to change different `UserDefault` `Boolean` Values to true based on a variable for instance in **psuedo-code**

```
func deductCoins() -> Bool {
    if price is greater than coins {

        tell the user that he/she doesnt have enough coins
    }
    if coins is greater than coins {
        tell the user he/she has bought the item
        change a UserDefault Boolean value
        if a value is different based on a parameter
        change a different value because of it
    }
}
```

i'm not that good at writing long complex functions and i used this function to only unlock one item in a `ViewController` but now i'm using CollectionView cells with different items in them and i want to unlock different content based on what the user picked using only one function

**-UPDATE 1-**

here is what i came up with its definitely not the best method but it works

```
//this Int value is set in the Index method in my collectionView 
var Int = 0

func deductCoins() -> Bool {

    if price > coins {
        label.text = String("You dont have enough coins")
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        return false
    }
    if coins >= price {
        if Int == 1 {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "ItemUnlocked")
            return true
        }
        if Int == 2 {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "ItemUnlocked")
            return true
        }
        if Int == 3 {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "ItemUnlocked")
            return true
        }
        if Int == 4 {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "ItemUnlocked")
            return true
        }
        if Int == 5 {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            return true
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

and here is the Index path method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        //the first item in my Index path is free it cost nothing
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy
    }
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        Int = 1
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy
    }
    if indexPath.item == 2 {
        Int = 2
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy

    }
    if indexPath.item == 3 {
        Int = 3
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy

    }
    if indexPath.item == 4 {
        Int = 4
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy

    }
    if indexPath.item == 5 {
        Int = 5
        //other things happen here i didnt post on purpose to keep some privacy
    }
}
```

and thats what i came up with and it works like i need it too if you guys have any other better methods please hit me up with an anwser and ill check it out

Comment: Keeping in app purchase booleans in user defaults is a big vulnerability. User defaults can be edited easily without your consent.

Comment: no no in-game content bought with in-game coins im not stupid enough to use UserDefaults for in-app purchases (because i use to hack games like that)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I'm assuming you will be having list of items in the game and when ever the user purchase each item you have to set purchase item flag as **true** and reduce the number of coins from the total coins.

And I'm also assuming you have the game data like

```
let gameList = [["level":"1", "name":"Saga","itemId":"10001","coinsRequired":10],
                ["level":"2", "name":"Rita","itemId":"10002","coinsRequired":20],
                ["level":"3", "name":"Villa","itemId":"10003","coinsRequired":10],
                ["level":"4", "name":"Corn","itemId":"10004","coinsRequired":5],
                ["level":"5", "name":"Leavy","itemId":"10005","coinsRequired":34],
                ["level":"6", "name":"Uhoo","itemId":"10006","coinsRequired":12]]
```

and now you can implement your game purchase

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let gameItem = gameList[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = gameItem["name"] as? String

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40)
    let gameStatus = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "ItemUnlocked\(gameItem["itemId"] as! Int)") as! Bool
    if gameStatus == true{
        // play the game
        button.titleLabel?.text = "Play"
    }else{
        // buy the item
        button.titleLabel?.text = "Buy\n $\(String(describing: gameItem["coinsRequired"]!))"
    }
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.tag = indexPath.row
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buyItemButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell?.accessoryView = button
    return cell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return gameList.count
}


func buyItemButtonTapped(_ aButton: UIButton){
    let gameItem = gameList[aButton.tag]
    buyIyem(itemId: gameItem["itemId"] as! Int)
}


@discardableResult
func buyIyem(itemId aItemId: Int) -> Bool {
    let price = gameList[aItemId]["price"] as! Int
    var totalCoins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "TOTAL_COINS")
    if price > totalCoins {
        // SHow "You dont have enough coins".
        return false
    }
    if totalCoins >= price {
        totalCoins = totalCoins - price
        UserDefaults.standard.set(totalCoins, forKey: "TOTAL_COINS")
        // handle the UI here
        UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "ItemUnlocked\(aItemId)")
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

I hope this will helps you in your implementation